# Proof of the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem using the convolution technique

Tags: calculus

> Let $a,b$ be two real numbers that satisfy $0<a<b<1$, a continuous
> function $f$ in $[0;1]$, and a positive number $\varepsilon$. Prove that
> there exists a polynomial $P(x)$ that satisfies
> $\underset{[a;b]}{\max} |f(x)-P(x)|<\varepsilon$.

Is there any way to approach this by using the convolution technique? I have seen many posts about proving this using the Lagrange Interpolating Theorem or Bernstein polynomial.

Comment: It might help if you'd explain by what you mean with convolution technique?

Answer (score 1):

There is a proof in Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" which uses this approach.

Assume without loss of generality that $a = 0, b = 1, f(0) = f(1) = 0$. Continue $f$ to be zero outside $[0,1]$. Then set
$$
Q_n(x) = C_n (1-x^2)^n
$$
where $C_n$ is such that $\int_{-1}^1Q_n(x) \, dx = 1$. Then define
$$
p_n(x) = f \ast Q_n(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)Q_n(x-y) \, dy = \int_0^1 f(y)Q_n(x-y) \, dy \, .
$$
Then $p_n$ is a polynomial of degree $2n$ and the $p_n$ converge uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$. *If $f$ has continuous derivatives, the corresponding derivatives of the $p_n$ converge uniformly, too.*

Comment: Very beautiful!